# OCI WAF migration to Azure Front door

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, azure-front-door

I'm inquiring about the practicality and factors that need to be considered.
A firm has utilized OCI WAF to shield its applications from harmful traffic. Positioned behind this WAF is a load balancer, which interacts with OCI WAF via port 443. The organization is interested in switching from OCI WAF to Azure Front Door but intends to retain the load balancer within the OCI cloud environment. Can this alteration be successfully made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with OCI, but in principal as long as the load balancer is publicly available it'll work.  You'd create the Azure Front Door and then use the load balancer as an endpoint origin.

It may be simple or difficult to configure Front Door to do exactly what the OCI WAF is doing currently.

Also you want to be certain that the load balancer is protected from non-Front Door traffic.  Whitelisting every Front Door IP that might call the load balancer could be challenging.  You may have a better scheme to secure that traffic in mind.